# BeanInstantiationException when injecting @Service into other @Service

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I have the following `@Service` class to my code:

```
@Service
public class FirstService {

    private final SecondService secondService;
    private final Client client;

    public FirstService(SecondService secondService) {
        this.secondService = secondService;
        this.client = Client.builder().setId(secondService.getId()).build();
    }
}


   

 @Service
 public class SecondService {
      
    private final ThirdService thirdService;
    
    public SecondService(ThirdService thirdService) {
        this.thirdService = thirdService;
    }
    
    public Id getId() {
       return new Id(thirdService.getId().toString());
    }
}
```

`ThirdService` is a `@Component` itself.

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsContructor
public class ThirdService {

    public UUID getId() {
       return UUID.randomUUID();
    }
}
```

Since I've added `FirstService`, all my tests start failing with the error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [xxx.xxx.xxx.FirstService]: Constructor threw exception
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.UUID.toString()" because the return value of "xxx.xxx.xxx.ThirdService.getId()" is null
```

Before that, tests worked fine. I'm guessing there is something wrong with how I've created `FirstService` but can't see what: looks like some error when injecting `SecondService` Can someone please help?

I'm using Spring boot 3.

Comment: I appreciate the attempt at an MCVE, but you seem to have left out the code that actually generates the error. Does your original `ThirdService` have a `getId()` method which is called in `FirstService`'s constructor?

Comment: Are you mocking the services? Returning null from method calls of mocks is perfectly normal, when you have not mocked that particular method - `ThirdService.getId()` in your case.

Comment: @Jorn you're right, I've added more details. Indeed, in FirstService's constructor I use some of the methods of SecondService: those in turn use some of the methods of ThirdService.

Comment: @Chaosfire All tests are failing, even those that have nothing to do with the services involved.

Comment: I'm not convinced that this code shows the full problem. The error mentions a `toString()` invocation *directly* on a `thirdService.getId()` call. You need to figure out where this happens. Perhaps the stack trace of the exception can help?

Comment: Sorry. I've updated the code. Check again please, that should be it: the error occurs in SecondService when it is making use of the method of ThirdService.

Comment: @Akinn That's to be expected, creating the application context fails for every test, because instantiating `FirstService` fails every time. You need to figure out why `thirdService.getId()` returns null. That's why i asked, if you are mocking the services for your tests.

Comment: I see ThirdService is always mocked in pre-existing tests and all of them working perfectly until I've added FirstService. Before that, ThirdService and SecondService existed and worked fine together with their test. I do not understand what this FirstService class introduced that breaks all tests though: I didn't even wrote the test class for FirstService yet... I rerun everything without FirstService and indeed it work.

Comment: @Akinn Before adding `FirstService`, `SecondService.getId()` was never invoked, thus `ThirdService.getId()` was never invoked and tests were fine. After adding `FirstService`, `ThirdService.getId()` eventually is invoked and this leads to NPE. Since you say the service is mocked, you need to mock the behaviour of `ThirdService.getId()`, since returning `null` is the default behaviour for method invocations of mocks.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of `SecondService` construction, the `ThirdService` bean is not been fully initialized yet, and it's generally not a good idea to perform logic in constructors of beans that depends on other beans.

You may want to use a `@PostConstruct` method to perform initialization after all dependencies have been injected and are ready to use:

```java
@Service
public class FirstService {

    private final SecondService secondService;
    private Client client;

    public FirstService(SecondService secondService) {
        this.secondService = secondService;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.client = Client.builder().setId(secondService.getId()).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried this approach but doesn't seem to solve the issue. I still get the same error: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'firstService': Invocation of init method failed. Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.UUID.toString()" because the return value of "xxx.xxx.xxx.ThirdService.getId()" is null

Comment: If you are mocking ThirdService in your tests, please ensure that the mock returns a non-null UUID when getId() is called. It's not an error of bean init anymore at least